# Visualizing a 4D object in 3D space using Blender

Tags: python, 3d-view, dimensions

Out of curiosity i am trying to visualize a 4D object in 3D space in Blender. I got the idea from and used some parts of the work done by Oleg Rybkin which can be found here: https://github.com/orybkin/Tesseract.

Using Python i extrude a standard Blender 3D object to the 4th dimension and by generating the 4D vertices, 4D Edges and 4D polygons of the 4D hypersphere.

To get the 3D view of the 4D object i use the Algebraic Form of the line-plane intersection formula described in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection) to determine the intersection of each 4D edge (consisting of 2 vertices each) with the 4D space defined by vertex [0,0,0,0] and normal [0,0,0,1].

I then disregard the fourth dimension completely of all the computed 4D intersections to get into the 3D realm (x,y,z,w -> x,y,z) and add 3D intersection in the Blender 3D Viewport and a ConvexHull Geometry Node to generate a 3D object.

The 3D object object generated in the Blender Viewport (no translation/rotation of the 4D object) i get is the same as the original 3D object (Cube, Sphere, Icosphere) which i believe is correct.
Unfortunately when translating (no rotation) a hypersphere in steps along only the w axis (4th dimension) I see the 3D sphere suddenly appearing 100% in size (when the 4D hypersphere enters the 3D subspace at w=0) and disappearing completely (when leaves the 4D hypersphere leaves the 3D subspace) while i should be seeing it appear gradually from from size 0%->100% and then gradually disappear from size 100%->0%. Rotating the 4D hypersphere also gives a 3D object which does not seem right (See this YouTube video on what i should be be seeing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0t4aKJuKP0Q).

I believe the problem must lie in either or both: (1) the line-plane intersection method i use to get the intersection vertex between all the 4D edges and the 4D space defined by vertex [0,0,0,0] and normal [0,0,0,1] and/or (2) the method i use to reduce the 4D intersection vertices to 3D.

Here's the Python method to get the intersections (segment = 4d edge, 2 vertices, normal = normal of 3D subspace = [0,0,0,1]:

```
""" Find the intersection vertices """
def edge4D_4Dplane_intersection(segment,normal):
    # find a point at the intersection of a realm and a segment
    # in case when the entire segments lies on the realm, returns two endpoints
    # segment is given as matrix 2x4
    segment=np.array(segment)
    # adapted from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection
    direction=segment[1]-segment[0]
    length=np.linalg.norm(direction)
    direction=direction/length
    if abs(direction.dot(normal)) < PRECISION:
        # segment is parallel to the realm
        if abs(segment[0].dot(normal)) < PRECISION:
            # segment is parallel and contained in the realm
            return segment
        else:
            # line is not intersecting with the realm
            return []
    else:
        # line is intersecting with the realm
        d = ([0,0,0,0]-segment[0]).dot(normal)/direction.dot(normal)
#        d = (object_origin4D_transformed-segment[0]).dot(normal)/direction.dot(normal)
        if d >= 0 and d <= length:
            # segment is intersecting with the realm
            vertex=[segment[0] + d*direction]
            return vertex
        else:
            return []
```

I believe this requires a more of a Geometric/Clifford Algebra answer. Even though i followed many YouTube presentations and read publications on this i was not able to find the concrete formulas given the 4D vertices/edges/polygons i have access to in Python.

Below a YouTube link which shows some examples of what what i am seeing (Blender 3D Viewport render) now using the methods described above. The video shows in sequence 3 rotations and 1 translation of a hypersphere (w in steps from -2.5 to +2.5 Blender units). As you can see with the translation the 3D sphere suddenly appears 100% as the translated hypersphere enters the 3D space and disappears completely when the hypersphere leaves the 3D space located at w=0.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iydz5ZvxB0

Any suggestions on improving the methods used or a nudge in the right direction is much appreciated.